# Pause AVAudioplayer for couple seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, pause

Iam using AVAudioplayer and I want to pause music for couple seconds when button is pressed and after 6 seconds I want to music start to play again without pressing any buttons. Is that even possible? and if it is, how can I do that?
Here are sample of my code:

```
NSString *soundPath2 =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background" ofType:@"wav"];

NSURL *soundURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath2];
NSError *error2 = nil;
self.backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL2 error:&error2];

self.backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = 9;
[self.backgroundMusic prepareToPlay];
[self.backgroundMusic play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know is it the right way to do this, but I did this

```
[self.backgroundMusic pause];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(continuePlay)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
                .........................

-(void)continuePlay{
[self.backgroundMusic play];
}
```

if I am wrong please correct me!